# Random rails partials 100 times slower than expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, rendering

I have a fairly large response view broken down into partials who's structure look like so, where * indicates this partial being loaded more than once:

`show

-responses

--response*

---comments

----comment*

---comment_form

-stats`

My problem is that depending on the size of the page, most of these partials take 10-20ms to render however a couple of these partials are taking 800-1000ms to render. There doesn't seem to be a pattern in which ones it is, ofter there are the same if I refresh quickly and often not.

Comment: assuming you are testing on mri, i would think that this is GC.

Comment: @msaspence what happen when you dont use partial does the overall time get reduce drastically

Comment: Yes if I dont use partials the overall time is reduced drastically, by around the amount that these anomalous partial loads add to. This isn't a great option for me as Its a big view file and I'll almost certainly be using the partials in other views at some point soon.

I am using mri, is there anything I can do to ease the cost of GC?

Comment: Thanks to @Viren pointing me at GC, done a lot of reading in this area  and understand the problem much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly use

`<%= render partial: 'partial', collection: @collection, as: c %>`

rather than

```
<% @collection.each do |c| %>  
  <%= render partial: 'partial', locals: { c: c } %>  
<% end %>
```

this is obvious, I dont know why I wasn't doing it. Provided some improvements but not a huge amount.

If you are running 1.9.3 upping these environment variables made a huge difference, knocking about 20% off the request:

```
RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS=600000 # This is 60(!) times larger than default
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=59000000 # This is 7 times larger than default
RUBY_HEAP_FREE_MIN=100000 # This is 24 times larger than default
```

via: http://www.web-l.nl/posts/15-tuning-ruby-s-garbage-collector-with-rvm-and-passenger

Comment: Changing Ruby GC parameters to improve your performances doesn't answer your question at all: even if it did a better job on your machine, it won't in many cases, and it is as if you were saying "How to spend more money? Try withdrawing more money from the cash machine"